# Which method to detect run mode of php script is more reliable?

Tags: php, runtime, webserver, command-line-interface, mode

I now to ways to detect weather php script runs in cli or web server mode:

```
if (defined('STDIN'))
```

or:

```
if (isset($argc))
```

Do they equally reliable or one of them is more  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither. Check the value returned from `php_sapi_name()`.

Comment: I thought answering with just a link is frowned upon, and the prefered way is to actually include some content....

Answer (score 1):

$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] won't be set, due to the lack of a HTTP request. I think defined( 'STDIN' ) or isset( $argc ) are reliable too, though. If it was up to me, I'd probably go with the defined( 'STDIN' ), as I can imagine someone accidentally setting a value to $argc.

The php_sapi_name function above seems to be another (the most reliable?) way of determining this, although I do think it'd be a good idea to read all the gotcha's: mind that different servers will give different answers.