# Methods to determine if PHP is running from a shell or within apache?

Tags: php, shell, apache2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to differentiate between http and cli requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172970/how-to-differentiate-between-http-and-cli-requests)
>   [Which method to detect run mode of php script is more reliable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436413/which-method-to-detect-run-mode-of-php-script-is-more-reliable)

What's the best method to determine if php is running from a shell (cron or otherwise) or running under apache?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172970/how-to-differentiate-between-http-and-cli-requests

Comment: you can use this library: https://github.com/arcanisgk/WEB-CLI-Detector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you might find this useful: http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php

Comment: you can use this library: https://github.com/arcanisgk/WEB-CLI-Detector

Answer (score 1):

```
echo php_sapi_name()==="apache2handler"; //running under apache?
```

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/5f9d5

Answer (score 0):

See marcelog's answer if you need to know the exact SAPI being used.

If all you need to know is whether you have an HTTP environment available, you can simply test for `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`:

```
$is_web = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```